# Generic reference and articles

Tags: articles, generic-noun-phrases

I can say, "a backpack is a useful item" or "backpacks are useful items" and both are grammatical and are referring to backpacks generally.

I can say, "a boat is a slow way to travel". But can I say, "boats are slow ways to travel"?

For some reason this last of the four sentences sounds odd to my ears. Maybe it's okay though?

Comment: I think the reason is that travelling by boat is _one_ way to travel - we wouldn't think of each individual boat as a different way - so it's "Boats are _a slow way_ to travel".

Comment: I guess I was looking for a grammatical reason. But maybe you're right–it's semantic?